# C++ Visual Studio Current Working Directory

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I have a similar problem to this:
[Current working directory is visual studio directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941439/current-working-directory-is-visual-studio-directory)

Except that I am working with a C++ project in Visual Studio. Any suggestions?

For example if I try the solution in the following post:
[GetCurrentDirectory for startup App. c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699301/getcurrentdirectory-for-startup-app-c)

I get this:

```
"C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 11.0\COMMON7\IDE"
```

But I want it to be the Debug folder under my project/solution folders.

Comment: As for C++-CLI there should be equivalents for all the suggested [tag:C#] classes and operations

Comment: It is project setting, Project + Properties, Debugging, Working Directory.

Comment: @HansPassant That is set to $(ProjectDir). How might I obtain that in my code?

Comment: IIRC, you can set the Working Directory to be `$(OutDir)` instead of project dir.  Then the current working directory path will be the actual location of the .exe (i.e.  "C:\Project Path\Debug" or something).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using the [_fullpath command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/506720ff.aspx) allowed me to extract the current directory. For example you can modify the example code on the linked page :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <direct.h>

void PrintFullPath( char * partialPath )
{
   char full[_MAX_PATH];
   if( _fullpath( full, partialPath, _MAX_PATH ) != NULL )
      printf( "Full path is: %s\n", full );
   else
      printf( "Invalid path\n" );
}

int main( void )
{
   // Get current directory
   PrintFullPath( ".\\" );
}
```